# Using variable names with regular expressions c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am working on a cross reference generator for class. In this project we are to iterate through a file and list all the words along with their line numbers and number of occurrences on that line like so:

A: 49:1

a: 9:1, 10:1, 12:2, 14:1, 17:2, 19:1, 26:1, 27:1, 28:2,
: 39:1, 41:1, 43:1, 45:2, 46:2, 49:1, 50:2, 51:1, 56:3,
: 81:1, 82:1, 94:1, 111:1, 112:1, 114:1, 117:1, 132:1, 135:1,
: 138:1, 142:2, 143:1, 144:1, 152:1, 156:1, 161:2, 163:1, 164:1,
: 167:1, 169:1, 175:1, 182:2, 190:1, 192:1

I am using a regular expression and a regex_iterator to find the number of occurrences of each word per line. 
My question is how would I use a variable name instead of a string literal?

For example:
instead of: `R"(\bthis\b)"`

I want to do this:

```
string word = "this";
R"(\bword\b)"
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: using the names of variables in strings at compile time is only possible with macros. If you accept run time cost, there is the possibilty of a map.

Comment: You could create a [regex pattern object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) by [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (see **case 6**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R"(\bthis\b)"` is a *raw string literal*, not a regexp literal, in case you were thinking that.  There are no regexp literals in C++, but `std::regexp` can be constructed from a character array or a `std::string`.

So you can simply do

```
string word = "this";
R"(\b)" + word + R"(\b)"
```

or, equivalently using plain old string literals

```
string word = "this";
"\\b" + word + "\\b"
```

**Note:** In both cases the result is a `std::string`, because `word` is a `std::string`.  This is different from `R"(\bword\b)"`, which is a character array.  Just in case the difference matters.

A word of **warning** though: the contents of word is probably coming from outside the program.  You need to quote it, since it may contain characters that are special in regular expressions.  Otherwise you're probably building a security vulnerability into your program.  You should be OK for a class exercise that noone besides your tutor is going to look at, but it is best to still put a line like

```
#warning "word" needs proper quoting to avoid security vulnerabilities
```

into your code, in case you try to reuse your code a year later when you have forgotten about this issue.  This way, the compiler will remind you.

Comment: I have a string:

str1= hello;
str2=hel;

And I am doing this to see if str1 has str2 in it:

regex e = str2]+"*";
        bool x=regex_match(str1,e);
        cout<<x;

I am getting this :
 error: conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::regex {aka std::__cxx11::basic_regex<char>}' requested
         regex e = str2+"*";